In Java, using Mockito fails to initialize MockMaker plugin
When I try to run this code:
package __6__240703.test.user_repository;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import __6__240703.main.user_repository.User;
import __6__240703.main.user_repository.UserRepository;
import __6__240703.main.user_repository.UserService;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import java.util.Optional;

public class UserServiceIntegrationTest {
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private UserService userService;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        userRepository = mock(UserRepository.class);
        userService = new UserService(userRepository);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetUserById() {
        User user = new User("1", "John Doe");
        when(userRepository.findById("1")).thenReturn(Optional.of(user));

        User result = userService.getUserById("1");
        assertNotNull(result);
        assertEquals("John Doe", result.getName());
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateUser() {
        User user = new User("2", "Jane Doe");

        userService.createUser(user);
        verify(userRepository, times(1)).save(user);
    }
}

I get this error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)

    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader$1.invoke(PluginLoader.java:84)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy10.isTypeMockable(Unknown Source)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.typeMockabilityOf(MockUtil.java:78)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockCreationValidator.validateType(MockCreationValidator.java:22)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.validatedSettings(MockSettingsImpl.java:274)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.build(MockSettingsImpl.java:235)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:86)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:2101)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:2016)
    at __6__240703.test.user_repository.UserServiceIntegrationTest.setUp(UserServiceIntegrationTest.java:19)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptLifecycleMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:128)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptBeforeEachMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:78)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeMethodInExtensionContext(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:520)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$synthesizeBeforeEachMethodAdapter$23(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:505)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachMethods$3(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:174)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachMethods(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:134)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Internal problem occurred, please report it. Mockito is unable to load the default implementation of class that is a part of Mockito distribution. Failed to load interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.DefaultMockitoPlugins.create(DefaultMockitoPlugins.java:104)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.DefaultMockitoPlugins.getDefaultPlugin(DefaultMockitoPlugins.java:78)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:75)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:50)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginRegistry.<init>(PluginRegistry.java:27)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.<clinit>(Plugins.java:22)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.<clinit>(MockitoCore.java:73)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.<clinit>(Mockito.java:1683)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.DefaultMockitoPlugins.create(DefaultMockitoPlugins.java:102)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoInitializationException: 
Could not initialize inline Byte Buddy mock maker.

I'm using these libraries:
enter image description here
I tried using jdk21 and jdk17. I also tried using the VM options '-XX:+EnableDynamicAgentLoading -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true' with no luck.
I also tried using the 'mock-maker-inline' line in the 'resources.mockito-extensions.org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker' file with no luck.

Aren't you just missing @SpringBootTest or @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) annotation for your test class?
